# how to stack notification using pushwoosh in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, pushwoosh

how to stack notification using pushwoosh when the app receive multiple message, i have search all over the internet but i didn't get answer. in this [reference](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-additional-platforms/xamarin-android/)

```
public void doOnMessageReceive(String message)
{
   // code to run when device receives notification
}
```

i should create a code in `doOnMessageReceive` when the app receive message so i create this code

```
const int intnumer = 100;
            var resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof (MainActivity));

            var stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
            stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Class.FromType(typeof (MainActivity)));
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);


            var resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .SetContentTitle("Yeah")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_home)
                .SetContentText(string.Format("The button has been clicked"));


            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(intnumer,builder.Build());
```

but the behavior is like when i receive the message this pop on notification bar[image: but the behavior is like when i receive the message this pop on notification bar![]

then click on it this will pop up [image]

anyone can help me?

Comment: you want when the notification clicked to pop a new notification? if yes install some local notification plugin and just fire new notification